# Android date issue

Tags: android, date, calendar

This thing is making me itch my head, what I want to is simple get the day from this date string

`2011-10-31 11:00:00`

I dont want to use `Date` since its deprecated, but I am not getting how to do it through `Calendar` class or any efficient way

Comment: Have a look at [This Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7724219/find-a-day-according-to-date-in-android/7724396#7724396)

Comment: But its still using Date and if I parse date it says deprecated

Comment: Do you have this date(ie `2011-10-31 11:00:00`) as a string?

Comment: I dont think Date is deprecated, just some of it's methods/constructors. It's still fine to use Date class in combination with DateFormat or Calendar

Comment: Its not but soon will just open the api all most everything is deprecated

Comment: I dont understand why is downvoting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step by Step:

1. Use a `SimpleDateFormat` to create a `Date`-object from your String
2. Use the Date with the `Calendar`s `setTime`-method to set it's date
3. Use the `Calendar`-object to get whatever you need.

A short example:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(new SimpleDateFormat("dd").parse(s));
int day_of_week = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
```

You migth add `TimeZone` and `Locale` to that. Also, `s` is your date-string.

Comment: Thanks very stupid to ask for me but its saying type mismatch

Answer (score 0):

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.newInstance()
cal.set(2011, 10, 31, 11, 0, 0)
int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
```

You can look at the documentation of the [Calendar class](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html) to see which fields you can set in order to get your date.

Comment: Thanks but they way I have to parse year, month manually and pass to calendar its very simple using Date I dont wanna use it as stated above

Comment: I thought you dont want to use Date?

Comment: Yeah I dont want to use date but this approach leads me to manual parsing

Comment: Then please clarify you question. Do you want to parse a String or what do you want to do?

Comment: Its simple I dont want to use date class and want to get day of the week from above given date

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `SimpleDateFormat` class parse the date and format the date.

```
String dateStr = "2011-10-31 11:00:00"; 

SimpleDateFormat curFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"); 
Date dateObj = curFormater.parse(dateStr); 

SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd");     // "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
String formattedDate = df.format(date);

Toast.makeText(this, formattedDate, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Check this and let me know

Comment: But I dont want pass current time its should be from string type date